# Django - how to make a link in an html template open an app and pass a objects value as a parameter

Tags: python, html, django

Hello I have an app that displays some database information in a table.  Inside of the html template I am making an edit link that I want to open another app(page viewLit) while passing a value to it's view.  I have added my code below.  My question is I am unsure of how to make this links url and pass the object data located inside circuit.circuitid along with it.  I haven't been able to find the right way to code this yet and this is just how I thought that this should be done. If anyone has a better idea I am open to suggestions.

```
search_custom.html(code for link)
{% for circuit in filter.qs %}
<tr>
    <td class="actions">
        <a href="?" class ="view-item" title ="View">View</a>
    </td>
    <td>{{ circuit.circuitid }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

myapp/myapp/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('viewLit/', include('viewLit.urls')),
]

myapp/viewLit/urls.py
urlpatterns=[
    path('viewLit/circuitid.id', views.viewLit, name='viewLit'),
]

myapp/viewLit/views.py
def viewLit(request, circuitid):
    #display records fields here
    return HttpResponse("You are at the viewLit page!")
```

Comment: Did you read the tutorial? This is completely explained there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation:
[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/)

myapp/viewLit/urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('viewLit/(?P<circuit_id>\w+)', views.viewLit, name='viewLit'),
]
```

html- template:

```
search_custom.html(code for link)
{% for circuit in filter.qs %}
<tr>
    <td class="actions">
        <a href="{% url 'viewLit' circuit.circuitid %}" class ="view-item" title ="View">View</a>
    </td>
    <td>{{ circuit.circuitid }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```